# Why does time conversion throw error ?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I am trying this

```
  declare @OpeningTime varchar(10)
Declare @OpeningTimeFormatted time(7)

Set @OpeningTime= '12:00pm'
Set @OpeningTimeFormatted= (Select CONVERT(time, CONVERT(varchar,CONVERT(date, getdate()))+ @OpeningTime, 120))

Select @OpeningTimeFormatted
```

but it throws error:

```
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

Comment: Why not just do `DECLARE @Time TIME(7) = '12:00pm';` It looks like you are over complicating a fairly straightforward task... Also, you should [**always** specify a length when converting to, or declaring varchar](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length)

Answer (score 1):

You need a space between your time and date. 
Just change OpeningTime to

```
Set @OpeningTime= ' 12:00pm'
```

or

```
Set @OpeningTimeFormatted= (Select CONVERT(time, CONVERT(varchar,CONVERT(date, getdate())) + ' ' + @OpeningTime, 120))
```

Otherwise your Date would look like `2017-02-1412:00pm`

Comment: But there's still some mis-thinking going on here since the `CONVERT(time,...` portion is going to throw away any date parts anyway. It's unclear what the OP is actually trying to achieve.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Yes, that's right. I don't know what the OP is expecting.

Comment: Maybe just convert from 12h to 24h

Answer (score 0):

You needed a space:

```
Set `@OpeningTimeFormatted= (Select CONVERT(time, CONVERT(varchar,CONVERT(date, getdate()))+ ' ' + @OpeningTime, 120))`
```

Answer (score 0):

You have declared `@OpeningTimeFormatted` as `time(7)` - it can't hold a date.
I suspect you want to get the current date at a specific time,
therefor you want to declare `@OpeningTimeFormatted` as `datetime2`:

```
declare @OpeningTime varchar(10)
Declare @OpeningTimeFormatted datetime2

Set @OpeningTime= '12:00pm'

SET  @OpeningTimeFormatted = convert(datetime2, 
                                     convert(char(10), getdate(), 120) +' '+
                                     convert(char(8), @OpeningTime, 120), 
                             120)

Select @OpeningTimeFormatted
```

Result:

```
14.02.2017 12:00:00 -- today, tomorrow of course the date would be different...
```

If, on the other hand, you simply want to get the time specified in the varchar, you only need `convert(time(7), @OpeningTime, 120)`.